# display google line chart with single value

Tags: google-visualization, linechart

I am using Google Line chart in my website. Using this chart I am creating daily/weekly/monthly reports. If it has only one value, it does not display the chart value. But I want to display that single value in Line Chart by default. Any ideas?

Comment: It will be helpful if you could post some code that you're using now.

Comment: If my answer below doesn't work for you, can you explain why so I can see if there's a way to improve it?  If it does work, please don't forget to up-vote and accept it.

Answer (score 6):

The best option is to change point size:

```
            var options = {'title': STR_BALANCE,
                           'width': 600,
                           'height': 300,
                           'pointSize': 3};

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('grafix'));
            chart.draw(dt, options);
```

Comment: it works to me! but I had the same problem with the image api, do you know how to change the 'pointSize'? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem in the past by doubling the number of points on the graph, doing a linear interpolation between points that exist, and if there is only a single point on the graph, drawing a horizontal line across three points.

For example, if I would normally have a data set of (0, 10), (1, 20), (2, 0), I'd map that to the set of points (0, 10), (1, 15), (2, 20), (3, 10), (4, 0).  Then if I end up with data set with only a single point, it's not much extra logic to go from (0, 30) to (0, 30), (1, 30), (2, 30), which will obviously give you a visible line.